# Dotnet highcharts drilldown: column to stacked column

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, graph, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I can accomplish basic drill down functionality in dotnet highcharts, meaning i can drill down a column chart into other column charts.

However i am attempting to drill down a column chart into a stacked column chart.
Meaning that for each column on level 1 there would be multiple stacked columns on level 2 (when you click the first regular column chart)

I am using dotnet highcharts and asp.net mvc.

I believe my problem lies when i drill down, as the code i have for a stacked column and regular column work, however when putting them together i cant seem to get the result im looking for.

So much like this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Animals',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'animals'
            }, {
                name: 'Fruits',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'fruits'
            }, {
                name: 'Cars',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'cars'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'animals',
                data: [
                    ['Cats', 4],
                    ['Dogs', 2],
                    ['Cows', 1],
                    ['Sheep', 2],
                    ['Pigs', 1]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'fruits',
                data: [
                    ['Apples', 4],
                    ['Oranges', 2]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'cars',
                data: [
                    ['Toyota', 4],
                    ['Opel', 2],
                    ['Volkswagen', 2]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

i want to drill down my column graph, but instead of having another layer of columns i would like stacked column.

I have tried adding plotoptions for normal stacking inside the drilldown method and have tried adding a stack tag to each instance of data, but none seem to be working.

Comment: At this moment, yon can drill to single serie not multiply. So you need to destroy chart and create new one.